# Jupyter on Anaconada on OSX, cells not showing results in browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Opening Jupyter 6.0.2 from Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12, on OSX 10.13.6, Cells in notebooks on "run cell", do not show results.

It seems the standard output of a cell upon running can not be returned to the notebook in the browser to be displayed.

This seems a small technical issue, but after many several hours and days, I can not resolve.

Experience of this behaviour first comes with downloading a workbook (scipy_con_2019-master.zip, open Jupyter notebook "2_Gaussian_HMM_INSTRUCTOR.ipynb" ).

Upon opening, this initially shows results below the various code cells. Working through from the beginning using run (Run Cell), as each cell is calculated the results disappear.  They are no longer shown. Thus preventing play, adaption, explore, learning.

To remove the possibility this behaviour is something to do with the downloaded notebooks, I created a new notebook with basic cell contents with simple commands like:

```
a=10
print(a)
```

or something as simple as

```
2*3
```

Upon run, same behaviour. No answer is returned for display below the code cell.

I note the integer number in brackets on far left does increase by 1 with each use of Run (run cell).

A full "stop kernal" and re-run all cells from the beginning, simply enforces behaviour to all cells in the downloaded notebook. That is, all results in the downloaded notebook all disappear.

Noting this behaviour is consistent to a downloaded notebook and a new created notebook, I suspect it is local settings, or conflict or set up issue.

As part of problem solving:

• I have ensured downloaded notebooks are identified as "trusted", and then re-opened and begun again. This makes no difference.

• This behaviour is with a full fresh download of Anaconda in the weeks before, around 20 May 2021. (Done in view of Navigator application would not complete an update as it requested. Full reinstall to update.)

• Is this a browser issue? Using Safari or Firefox as browser makes no difference to this behaviour.

• Search of key words, and key fault line in terminal, on Google search, or stack overflow or Superuser were not successful in finding a relatable solution.

Looking in terminal opened for each Jupyter session, I get the following identified error consistently, hence I think this is helpful to resolve the source of this issue, though beyond my limited coding knowledge to interpret and resolve the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 546, in run_callback
result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 274, in open
self.create_stream()
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 127, in create_stream
meth = getattr(km, 'connect' + channel)
AttributeError: 'MappingKernelManager' object has no attribute 'connect_control'
```

I am wondering if the issue relates to permissions or an incompatable component, or possibly arising in view of security upgrades in Jupyter (those pages read to seek answer to this). It seems the standard output of a cell upon running can not be returned to the notebook in the browser to be displayed.

I have posted this issue first on the ContinuumIO/anaconda - issues git hub page: [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12434) however I do not think this site is very active.

Comment: If I am missing something obvious, do please point it out.  Until resolved just not able to use Jupyter and notebooks.  Frustrating.  Have done all I can think off to resolve this issue without posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to download the recent newer release:  Anaconda3-2021.05-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg once again.

Install initially failed. Then seemed to work, as in files were copied, then advised install had failed.

I noted an older master Anaconda file on the HD (highest level on HD) had not been updated since 2018. Hence, clearly this was not being updated by the recent installation process.

Deleted that Anaconda folder.

Then the install of the latest release did work.

It was not immediately easy to find where the new Anaconda files were installed.

The new installation was in the OSX User account folder, in a folder called "opt".

Now 1+1 shows the answer in a Jupyter file.  Joy.

[image: Screen image]